# PropType validation is throwing an error because of RoutingContext

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I'm getting the following error for all the props that I am validating:

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `assetType` was not specified in `AssetManagementShow`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.

Warning: Failed propType: Required prop `assetTypes` was not specified in `AssetManagementTransactionsFecher`. Check the render method of `RoutingContext`.
My Routes look like this:

```
  <Route path='asset_management' component={AssetManagementContainer} >
      <IndexRoute component={AssetManagementIndex} />

    <Route path=':name' component={AssetManagementTransactionsFetcher}>
        <IndexRoute component={AssetManagementShow} />
        <Route path=':transactionKey' component={TransactionsShow} />
    </Route>
  </Route>
```

I'm getting this error when trying to render AssetManagementShow (and TransactionsShow). I'm getting an error from the props of both AssetManagementTransactionsFetcher and AssetManagementShow.

The AssetManagementContainer only fetches data and renders the child route using React.cloneElement. AssetManagementTransactionsFetcher does the same - it fetches data and renders the child route with new props.

I think this is where the problem arises. When I pass props to a child route using React.cloneElement, the child route does not validate its PropTypes properly.

I'm running react-router v1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just the way that that prop type validation works with `cloneElement` – the validation is done on element creation, rather than on mount.

More details and references are available here: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/upgrade-guides/v1.0.0.md#routehandler.